# AS3 Air How to I set the PrintJob DPI?

Tags: actionscript-3, printing, air, dpi

My photo printer returns a pixel dimensions of 448 x 295. In the printer options I can see that the resolution is 2152 x 1416 (for 6 x 4 inch), If I set my sprite to 2152 x 1416 it comes out way to big.

How do I provide a Sprite at the right scale / DPI?

I have tried:

```
_printOptions = new PrintJobOptions();
_printOptions.pixelsPerInch = 346;
```

But gives: Error #1056: Cannot create property [pixelsPerInch](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJobOptions.html#pixelsPerInch) on flash.printing.PrintJobOptions

**UPDATE:**

So as Khaled Garbaya mentions below make sure the project is set to use AIR 2, set the DPI option, have the bitmapData at 2152 x 1416, and add as a child to a sprite which is set at 448 x 295, hit print and comes out great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your projet is set to run on AIR 2 or plus And make sure to set the movieClip properties that you will use to print to public

Comment: Do you know how I would do that on Flash Develop? I just select new AIR AS3 Projector as my project.